# Geodesic of a cone

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $C$ be the cone parametrized by:
$$ X(u,v)=(v\cos u, v\sin v, v) . $$
Prove that a parallel of this cone is not a geodesic of this surface.

---

I know that a geodesic would be the equivalent of a "straight line", but in a Riemannian manifold. However, I'm not sure why the problem means by "parallel". Also, I've been reading DoCarmo but still haven't been able to solve the problem.

Comment: Go around the circle at constant speed. What is the acceleration vector? For the curve to be a geodesic, how should the acceleration be related to the surface?

Comment: Look up Clairaut's relation

Comment: @WillJagy: Parallels are exempt from Clairaut, as every parallel makes a constant angle with itself. Of course, in general, some parallels can be geodesics and most will not be.

Comment: @TedShifrin  thanks. Now you have me curious.

Comment: @WillJagy Not on the cone, of course! 

Comment: You should ask whoever posed this problem what a parallel is. A reasonable guess is a level set $v=c$.

Comment: Then figure out what @TedShifrin asked. Answering his question is more important than this specific example.